# Convert SVS images to MRSX format

Tags: image, data-conversion

I wish to convert Aperio AFI microscope .svs files from a pathology lab microscope into 3DHistech .mrxs format. Lab ppl have some pipeline X and they asked me to look into the matter.

I can read the SVS files via [openslide](https://github.com/openslide/openslide-python) or [openmicroscopy](https://www.openmicroscopy.org/index.html). Conversion to 'regular' pictures (tiff, for instance). I figure out that since [openslide](https://github.com/openslide/openslide-python) can read mrxs, writing this format should be feasible too, but can't find any (free) software to do this. I don't care about any specialties, just need the end result to be readable by Histech readers.

Can anyone help with the conversion? Lacking full software, I could try to code writer if resulting file description is available.

I already asked [bioinformatics](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/21143/converting-convert-svs-files-into-mrxs-format) for help.